# Generics how to resolve incompatible generic type constraints

Tags: c#

I have the following generic class:

```
public class MyDbSetWrapper<T> : IDbSetWrapper<T>
        where T : class, IEntity
{

}
```

I want to create a new instance of this class from the `GetSet` method below. The following does not compile because `MyDbSetWrapper` expects `T` to be an `IEntity`, yet `TEntity` isn't constrained to be an `IEntity` in the `GetSet` method:

```
public IDbSetWrapper<TEntity> GetSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
     return new MyDbSetWrapper<TEntity>();
}
```

As `GetSet` is an implementation of the 3rd-party interface, I'm unable to alter the generic constraint on this method to include `IEntity`, even though `TEntity` will always be an `IEntity`.

How can I create a new instance of `MyDbSetWrapper` from the `GetSet` method?

Comment: You can remove the `IEntity` type constraint and do a run-time check to see that the type passed implements `IEntity`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Actually, you can't; that will prevent you from using members of the type.

Comment: @SLaks It will, but does the OP need to use members of the type?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes I do. Perhaps I could remove the IEntity constraint as you suggested, and cast to IEntity when I need to access members of the type, as TEntity will always be an IEntity.

Comment: @aw1975 That is a possible solution, though not compile time safe :\

Comment: Why will `TEntity` always be an `IEntity`?  This is a public method; it can be called by the public and they can pass in `string` for `TEntity` if they want. Saying that *you* promise to follow this contract isn't good enough; the type system needs to know that *everyone* will do so.

Comment: Let me put it another way. The interface you are implementing *requires* that you be willing to accept `string` as a type argument. You are not willing to do so. Therefore **you are not willing to implement the interface**. Find a different interface that you are willing to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do this at compile time. As you noticed yourself, in order to create a new `MyDbSetWrapper<TEntity>` you need to ensure that `TEntity` satisfies at least the same type constraints as needed by the `MyDbSetWrapper<>` type. Since you cannot do that, you can’t create the type with compile-time type-safety.

If you can’t move the `IEntity` type into an accessible location, you can only use reflection here:

```
public IDbSetWrapper<TEntity> GetSet<TEntity>()
    where TEntity : class
{
    var type = typeof(MyDbSetWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity));
    return (MyDbSetWrapper<TEntity>) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

Note that this requires that `IDbSetWrapper<T>` does not have a constraint on `IEntity` either though. Otherwise it won’t work as you you could not guarantee (again) that `TEntity` in the return type `IDbSetWrapper<TEntity>` satisfies the constraints.